# Solidity variable for contract scope (not state variables)?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-estimate, state-variable, local-variables

I use state variables for the interaction of calls (fallback) between contracts. But copying and clearing state variables uses a lot of gas.

Perhaps there is a better practice, how to have temporary variables in the contract scope?

```
bytes private myGloabalVar;

function func(calldata params, address target) {
    delete myGloabalVar;
    myGloabalVar = params;//too much gas is used here
    target.call('0x1234');//with callback
    delete myGloabalVar;
}

fallback() external payable {
    //use myGloabalVar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary variables live only at the point of procedure execution. If the value in myGloabalVar is needed only for mutex definition, I will suggest a better way:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract FixedEtherVault {
    uint internal locked = 1;

    modifier noReentrant() {
        require(locked == 1, "No re-entrancy");
        locked = 2;
        _;
        locked = 1;
    }
    
    //bytes private myGloabalVar;

    function func(bytes calldata params, address target)external noReentrant {
        // delete myGloabalVar;
        // myGloabalVar = params;//too much gas is used here
        target.call('0x1234');//with callback
        // delete myGloabalVar;
    }
}
```

You spend gas to write to storage and then get half that amount if you write 0 to the same slot. Which is still a lot = 10000.

It is better to always leave a value in the slot (in this case 1 and 2) and then the cost will be reduced.

Comment: Value in myGloabalVar is needed for processing in callback functions. Thanks for the advice on gas savings